# Convert a bunch of images to lmdb format in matlab

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, leveldb, caffe

I am using caffe deep network library and I have to use googlenet in my data (images).

The problem is the fact that I want to do a lot of pre-processing operations, and I don't want to save every image processing operation as image files and then execute create_imagenet.sh included in the library. This library needs text files to indicate where are the train and validation image files.

I don't want to save a lot of images and then converting them in LMDB.

All I want is to do the image processing operation in a series of images and save them in a row in a lmdb file to be read by caffe later.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This github repository might be the one you are actually looking for:
https://github.com/kyamagu/matlab-lmdb